# Injecting objects created via hk2+jersey returns null

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0, hk2

I have the following resource class

```
@Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorldResource {
@Inject
private UserAuthorizationRepository userRepository;

@GET
public Response sayHello(@Context UriInfo uriInfo)
```

Following is my implementation of UserAuthorizationRepository

```
public class UserAuthorizationRepositoryImpl implements UserAuthorizationRepository { 
@Inject
private MyUserIdToUserNameTable userIdToUserNameTable;
public String getUserName(Long userId) {
    userNameToUserIdTable.getUserName(userId)
}
```

and I have register the following binder to the ResourceConfig

```
public class RepositoryBinder extends AbstractBinder {
@Override
protected void configure() {
    bind(new UserAuthorizationRepositoryImpl()).to(UserAuthorizationRepository.class);
    bind(new MyUserIdToUserNameTable()).to(UserIdToUserNameTable.class);
}
```

After this, the userRepository in my resource class is binding correctly, however, the userIdToUserNameTable in the UserAuthorizationRepositoryImpl is null.

Does anyone know the reason? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, it looks like you are creating the UserAuthorizationRepositoryImpl yourself rather than letting hk2/Jersey create it.  You might want to instead try:

```
public class RepositoryBinder extends AbstractBinder {
@Override
protected void configure() {
    bind(UserAuthorizationRepositoryImpl.class).to(UserAuthorizationRepository.class);
    bind(MyUserIdToUserNameTable.class).to(UserIdToUserNameTable.class);
}
```

That will allow hk2/Jersey to create the classes, and properly inject them.

Comment: This does not work as in now the userRepository becomes to null as well